# Keep my drivers after kernel update

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, kernel

I recently installed ubuntu 10.04 in a new notebook and I had to add the Ralink 3090 v2.3.13 driver because wifi didn't work.
The problem is I lose the driver every time the kernel updates, I know this happens sometimes but it's kind of annoying having to install it every time.
Is there a way to prevent this for happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DKMS to automatically rebuild the driver every time you update the kernel. To do this you'll have to install the source package, create a DKMS config file for it, and set it up.

There's an example of how to do it on CentOS [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules#head-d313bd351f90d4f25a2143b7bbcff73f927731f0). That uses the 'cifs' module, so you'll need to replace that with whatever your driver is.

For Ubuntu, the instructions should be pretty much the same - just install dkms, 'build-essential' and your kernel sources first. Also, if you don't have a root account, don't forget to prepend each command with 'sudo'.

There's also a LinuxJournal article with a lot of information on DKMS here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6896

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know if this will work, but you could try installing Dynamic Kernel Module Support.

```
aptitude install dkms
```